# 4 bit Year and decade counter

Tags: algorithm, overflow

So I came across this problem and I can't figure an elegant solution, maybe someone can point me in the right direction. 
Say I have a *4 bit* `counter` (so it can count from `0-15` in decimal) for number of years elapsed. On year `16`, the year counter will overflow and reset back to `0`, on year `17` it will be `1` and so on. I also have a `decade` counter that will have the value `1` for years `10` through `19`, value `2` for years `20` through `29` and so on. 
How can I get the total number of years elapsed if I have the yearCounter and decadeCounter information?

E.g. `decade = 1` and `counter = 2`; `year = 18`.

Is there a *name* for this kind of problem? And is there a function that can calculate the number of `year`s from these `counter`s up to `decade` overflows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the problem is *modulo arithmetics*; providing that `year` is not *negative* we have

```
 decade  = year / 10
 counter = year % 16
```

Reversed formula (which you are looking for) is

```
 year = decade * 10 + (16 - (decade * 10) % 16 + counter) % 16
```

where `%` is *remainder* and `/` is *integer division*.

For instance, if `year = 2018` we have

```
decade  = 2018 / 10 = 201
counter = 2018 % 16 = 2
```

and the reversed formula gives

```
year = 201 * 10 + (16 - (201 * 10) % 16 + 2) % 16 =
       2010 + (16 - 2010 % 16 + 2) % 16 =
       2010 + (16 - 10 + 2) % 16 =
       2010 + 8 % 16 =
       2010 + 8 =
       2018
```